# 2D representation of a 1D input sample in deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, reshape

I want to design a 2D-CNN model for the dataset called "CICIoT2023". I will provide the link to this data set : https://www.unb.ca/cic/datasets/iotdataset-2023.html

This data set is divided into 168 csv, and in each csv file, there are 46 features + 1 label to classify each sample.

Because the number of features is 46, I can not reshape the data into a 2D format properly. It will be 23x2 in the best case. Is there a way to represent each row of this data set to a 2D image with proper width and height?

I appreciate any help of any kind in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not sure why do you even want to apply convolution on tabular data. Anyways, even if you want to do it, you should use a 1D convolution kernel (PyTorch [Conv1d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html), Tensorflow [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D)).

To use 1D Convs, you should resize your data to (1, 46), where 1 is the channel dimension.